# Incorrect Syntax Error in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server-2008

```
UPDATE SHIPPER_LINE
SET ACT_FREIGHT =
convert(decimal(10,2),
(CASE

WHEN CAST(RATE AS FLOAT) >= 0 AND CAST(RATE AS FLOAT) <= 105 THEN    
CAST(RATE AS FLOAT) * 1.2

WHEN CAST(RATE AS FLOAT) >= 105.01 AND CAST(RATE AS FLOAT) <= 145.99 THEN 
CAST(RATE AS FLOAT) = 146

WHEN CAST(RATE AS FLOAT) >= 146 THEN CAST(RATE AS FLOAT) * 1.06

ELSE CAST(Rate AS Float)

END))
```

The above is part of an existing trigger I'm editing. I'm getting a syntax error under the '=' sign on the 'Cast(rate as float) = 146' section. What is the proper syntax to make the 'Rate' equal 146 when within the specified range?

Comment: Try a convert along with your case statement and see if that fixes the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you trying to update `RATE` or use the value 146

You cant do the first here, the second just return 146

```
UPDATE SHIPPER_LINE
SET ACT_FREIGHT = convert(DECIMAL(10, 2), (
            CASE 
                WHEN CAST(RATE AS FLOAT) >= 0
                 AND CAST(RATE AS FLOAT) <= 105
                    THEN CAST(RATE AS FLOAT) * 1.2
                WHEN CAST(RATE AS FLOAT) >= 105.01
                 AND CAST(RATE AS FLOAT) <= 145.99
                    THEN 146    -- just return the value
                WHEN CAST(RATE AS FLOAT) >= 146
                    THEN CAST(RATE AS FLOAT) * 1.06
                ELSE CAST(Rate AS FLOAT)
                END
            ))
```

Comment: This worked perfectly. My mistake was to include the '=' sign.